# How do I get the Flask package tutorial work with Poetry?

Tags: python, flask, python-poetry

I'm using Poetry to manage my Python project (dependencies, package, etc) and I'm trying to implement the four-line hello world from Flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/#simple-packages

My folder structure looks like this:

```
myproject/
  .venv/
  myproject/
    __init__.py
    views.py
  poetry.lock
  pyproject.toml
  README.rst
```

The two files, **init**.py:

```
import myproject.views
__version__ = '0.1.0'

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

And views.py:

```
from myproject import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello world'
```

Yet when I run export FLASK_APP=myproject and FLASK_ENV=development and do `flask run`, and point my browser to the port, it says

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "myproject", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myproject.views
  File "/myproject/myproject/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from myproject import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'myproject' (most likely due to a circular import) (/myproject/myproject/__init__.py)
```

How can I fix this? I'd like to use the recommended pattern.

Comment: try running `poetry shell` first. as for the circular imports, there's a note in the page you linked.

Comment: I have, I'm doing all of this in the virtual env

Answer (score 9):

In your terminal, type `poetry run flask run`.

Comment: That's incorrect. The previous answer was correct

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue comes from importing the views *at the top* of `__init__.py`. Try moving the import statement to the end of the file, just like the tutorial does.

Comment: Thanks. The vscode python extension won't allow. It automatically moves it to the top... Why?